# Retravel Database value according to the username and password Qt C++

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I'm try to re-travel MYSQL database value to the QLine edit. I want to re-travel data according to the username and password. Username and password are in mainwindow.cpp. After login successfully, it's open second window named userdetails.cpp. I want to display data in this userdetails.cpp. This is the code I used in this moment.

```
    void Userdetails::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{

    {
            // database connection
            QSqlDatabase database;
            database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL","MyConnect");
            database.setHostName("localhost");
            database.setUserName("root");
            database.setPassword("");
            database.setDatabaseName("electricity");

            if(database.open()) {

                QSqlQuery query(database);


                if (query.prepare(QString("SELECT accno, fullname, address, telephone FROM user_reg_elec WHERE username = :username AND password = :password"))) {

                    //Add bindings
                    query.bindValue(":username","username");
                    query.bindValue(":password","password");
                    if(query.exec()) {

                        while(query.next()) {
                            ui ->dislayaccountnumber ->setText(query.value(0).toString());
                            ui ->displayname ->setText(query.value(1).toString());
                            ui ->displayaddress ->setText(query.value(2).toString());
                            ui ->displattelephoneno ->setText(query.value(3).toString());
                            // ui ->displayamountoebill ->setText(query.value(4).toString());
                        }
                    } else {
                        qDebug() << "Query did not execute due to: " << query.lastError().text();
                        QMessageBox::information(this, "Query did not execute", "Not successful executing the query");
                    }
                } else {
                    qDebug() << "Query not prepared due to the following error: " << query.lastError().text();
                }
            } else {
                qDebug() << "Database not opened due to: " << database.lastError().text();
                QMessageBox::information(this, "Database not open", "Not opened successfully");
            }

            database.close();
        }

        QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("MyConnect");
       }
```

Comment: Could you show us the error and tell us properly what is exactly your problem?? Could you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I want to re-travel data according to the username and password that type in the main window. In here I'm bind one group of username and password.(query.bindValue(":username","username")  query.bindValue(":password","password")) But I want to get username and password according to the user type in the main window.  Is it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your application accepts a user (using a login phase), you should save the user id in your application and pass it using a set function member or even as parameter in your ctor of UserDetails. So, when your application displays the user details, you can create a SQL query referring directly the user throw her/him id, avoiding use any other field in `where` clausule.

A suggestion:

```cpp
class Userdetails
{
private: 
  std::string _user;
...
setUser(const std::string & user){
  _user = user;
}
...
}
```

But, I strongly recommend, for security reasons, the password should not be used, you already log in your user, and the user id IS unique.